# Find angle $\alpha$ from a complex vector

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I'm trying to solve this problem from a Russian book:

> Find the angle which is needed to rotate the vector $3\sqrt{2} + i2\sqrt{2}$ to obtain the vector $-5+i$.

**EDIT:** $\tan\dfrac{\pi}{6} \neq \dfrac{2}{3}$, so I'm wrong in most of what I've done.

Is there another way to solve this (I did this the wrong way :P )?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks! :)

Comment: $\cos \frac{\pi}{6} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, you have the wrong angle.

Comment: @DanielFischer, where am I wrong? I can't find the mistake

Comment: TX286: @Daniel Fisher is saying that  $3\sqrt{2} + i2\sqrt{2} = \sqrt{26} \left[ \cos{\left( \dfrac{\pi}{6} \right)} + i\sin{\left( \dfrac{\pi}{6} \right)} \right]$ is wrong so you should not be using $\frac{\pi}{6}+\alpha$ later on.

Comment: The argument $\varphi$ of $3\sqrt{2} + i2\sqrt{2}$ has the tangent $\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3\sqrt{2}} = \frac{2}{3}$. But $\tan \frac{\pi}{6} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: Oh yes! You're right, let me fix that then. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Divide $-5+i$ by $(3+2i)\sqrt2$.

Comment: Why I can do that? I can't see the reason :(

Comment: Because multiplication of complex numbers *adds* the arguments (angles wrt the real axis), hence division *subtracts* arguments. And you are after the difference between the two arguments.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't see that! :D

Answer (score 1):

The answer is
$$
\arg(\frac{-5+i}{3+2i}) = \arg((-5+i)(3-2i)) = \arg(-13+13i) = \arg(-1+i)= 3\pi/4
$$

Comment: How do you know this? I know $-5+i$ and $3+2i$ are the vectors of the problem, and arg(z) is the angle I'm trying to find, but... I can't see why I have to divide that way :(